Should I remove young tomato's first flowers?
My case is rather experiment, because usually the gardeners first make them to sprout and grow in pots, then move to final place in the garden.
I decided to let them to sprout and grow at final place in my garden, from beginning to end. So, I got them to sprout in the middle of May. Now, they are approx 30 cm tall, while that variety is going to reach 1-1.5 meters
That's how they look now:

First flowers appear at the top of the plant (not open yet).
How do you think: should I remove first flowers now to prevent too early fruit so they will stop grow, or leave everything as is?

You should probably mulch the soil to stop dirt splashing onto the leaves with rain or irrigation, which seems to be happening in this picture. That is how most of the fungal "blights" infect tomato plants.

What specific variety of tomato is this - it's local varierty developed in my country, I don't think it even has english name. But it's determinate eraly variety

To be specific: https://sklep--nasiona-pl.translate.goog/pomidor-ondraszek-gruntowy-na-przetwory-i-do-bezposredniego-spozycia.html?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=pl&_x_tr_hl=pl&_x_tr_pto=wapp

Doesn't need an English name. https://gardenseedsmarket.com/tomato-ondraszek-field-variety-for-preserves-and-direct-consumption.html

Very good variety btw

Your tomato looks great. Just leave everything as it is - do not remove those flowers or you'll just decrease your yield.

I'm surprised they started flowering so small, will they continue grow + producing fruits at the same time?

I don't see why not; mine flower while small and flower until the blight/septoria get them in September.


to prevent too early fruit so they will stop grow

That's not how tomatoes work.
You either have determinate tomatoes, that will stop (regardless of anything you do, so removing flowers will just reduce yeild) when they are ready to ripen off a bunch of fruit and die.
Or you have indeterminate tomatoes, that will grow and set fruit until something else (frost or blight, typically) stops them. In areas without frost they can grow and fruit for years if blight (or a hurricane) doesn't get them. Removing first flowers will both reduce and delay your yield.
Since your Ondraszek tomato is determinate you don't really want to prune much of anything. Good luck! The main issue with direct planting in cool climates is beating the frost on the time to harvest.

That's determinate variety

I can expect first frost in October, not earlier so I think it should be possible to harvest before frosts
